# my .env.testing is not used for my laravel tests

Tags: laravel, testing

I work with Laravel **10**.

For the tests, I have defined a `.env.testing` file in which there is a dedicated database.

When I run the tests, it is the database declared in the `.env` file which is used.

I tried to clear the config with `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan config:clear --env=testing`

Without succes : the `.env.testing` file is never used.

What is my mistake ?

**edit :**

- I forgot to precise that it is "dusk" tests. So I run the command `php artisan dusk`
- And if I run the command `php artisan dusk --env=testing`, then the `.env.testing` is used. It is only when I run the command without the environment that the problem appears. According to the documentation it is not normal.
- I use the `phpunit.xml` and `phpunit.dusk.xml` supplied by the frameworks, without any modifications inside.

The phpunit.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <source>
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </source>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <!-- <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/> -->
        <!-- <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/> -->
        <env name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

and the phpunit.dusk.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Browser Test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Browser</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: `php artisan test --env=testing`? Have you checked your `phpunit.xml` config file?

Comment: Share your `phpunit.xml` please

Comment: BAck when I used dusk I always had to pass in the `--env`  option to make sure it wouldn't screw anything up.

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/dusk#environment-handling

states that you should use `.env.dusk.testing` as the filename (or any other environment your application is in).

Comment: Hi Flam, I just tried and it is the same : it is the wrong database which is used. But thanks for the help. I think I will give up "dusk" and make the tests like I did before.